# how would I pass value to SLOT function in qt?

Tags: qt, qt5

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)  { for(int j=0;j<2,j++)  {
        snapshot_action[k]=new QAction(this);
        snapshot_action[k]->setIconText("Snapshot");
        control_menu[k]->addAction(snapshot_action[k]);
        connect(snapshot_action[k], &QAction::triggered, this, &SimplePlayer::snap_fun);}}
```

With initially `k=0;`
I have omitted code which lays out four views each with snapshot action. ( for simplicity).

Now the problem is when I press snapshot action button of any view I should know somehow that snapshot action button of THAT particular window is pressed.

How can I?

How would I pass value of to my snap function?

Do I need to store values of 'k' in some array? (some bad idea)

Comment: You could use [`QObject::sender()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to get the sender of the signal

Comment: Try [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `QSignalMapper`:

```
QSignalMapper m_mapWidget;
```

In the code:

```
connect(&m_mapWidget, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(snap_fun_k(int)));
```

loop k:

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), &m_mapWidget, SLOT(map()));
m_mapWidget.setMapping(action, k);
```

Note that you'll want the lifetime of the signal mapper to be at least as long as you want it to perform the mapping.